# Specify type of Jinja2 variable in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jinja2, fastapi

Is it possible to assign a "type" or class to a variable passed to a Jinja template in Pycharm?

Specifically, similar to what is done in IntelliJ IDEA for Freemarker templates using this declaration in a comment:

```java
<#-- @ftlvariable name="foo" type="java.lang.String" file="path/to/file" -->
```

See here for a reference as to how they do it:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html#7b90b664

After the above comment/annotation is included in the template file, the variable "foo" has a type reference to java.lang.String and auto-complete works for it. I'm not asking for anything complicated, just for fields on a class. E.g.:

```
{{ author.Name }}
```

In the above example, it would be ideal if Name and other fields would be listed/populated.